# Vue router link add object in the url

Tags: vue.js

This is my setting:

- `main.js` creates a vue and attaches the component App to an element in the dom
- `router.js` sets the routs
- `App.vue` has the `router-view` and a few `router-link`s

Problem:

- the link `<router-link to="/admin">Admin1</router-link>` works fine
- the link `<router-link to="{name: 'admin'}">Admin2</router-link>` doesn;t work and adds to the url bar: `#/{name: 'admin'}`

Am I using the router in the wrong way?
Below my files in details

---

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import router from './router'
import App from './App'

new Vue({
  router,
  el: '#app',
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>',
  data: {
  }
})
```

router.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'

import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld'
import Marketplace from '@/components/Marketplace'
import Admin from '@/components/Admin'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'HelloWorld',
      component: HelloWorld
    },
    {
      path: '/marketplace',
      name: 'marketplace',
      component: Marketplace
    },
    {
      path: '/admin',
      name: 'admin',
      component: Admin
    }
  ]
})
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <p>
      <router-link to="/">Home</router-link>
      <router-link to="/admin">Admin1</router-link>
      <router-link to="{name: 'admin'}">Admin2</router-link>
    </p>
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App'
}
</script>
```

Comment: since its json object, you should change to paramter to :to

Comment: I LOVE STACKOVERFLOW

Answer (score 3):

In order for your `to="{name: admin}"` to work without adding the char `#`, do the following inside your router config file.

Also you are supposed to use the `v-bind` for `to=""`.

Use `v-bind:to="{name: 'admin'}"` or `:to="{name: 'admin'}"`

Example:

```
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  // whatever you have
})
```

Source: https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html